# Is there a way to simulate a foreach in Django using queries?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a model 'Status' with a ManyToManyField 'groups'. Each group has a ManyToManyField 'users'. I want to get all the users for a certain status. I know I can do a for loop on the groups and add all the users to a list. But the users in the groups can overlap so I have to check to see if the user is already in the group. Is there a more efficient way to do this using queries?

edit: The status has a list of groups. Each group has a list of users. I want to get the list of users from all the groups for one status.

**Models**

```
class Status(geomodels.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        username = self.user.user.username
        return "{0} - {1}".format(username, self.text)

    user = geomodels.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='statuses')
    date = geomodels.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
    groups = geomodels.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='receivedStatuses', null=True, blank=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name + " - " + self.user.user.username

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name='groupsIn')
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='groups')
```

Comment: Can you show us your models?

Comment: Based on your model code, you want the members rather than user for the groups in the requested status, right? Since each group can only have one user with this code I assume you're trying to follow the m2m relation.

Comment: Yes thats correct. I want to aggregate the members of all the groups.

Comment: @GeorgeMuresan - I have updated my answer based on your posted model code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a list of the groups I was looking for and then querying all users that were in any of those groups. This should be pretty efficient as I'm only using one query.

```
statusGroups = []
    for group in status.groups.all():
        statusGroups.append(group)

    users = UserProfile.objects.filter(groupsIn__in=statusGroups)
```

Comment: If you want to do it that way rather than the way I showed, `statusGroups = list(status.groups.all())` is more efficient. You can also use a queryset for your `__in` filter, which does a subquery and may or may not be faster depending on your database: `UserProfile.objects.filter(groupsIn__in=status.groups.all())`

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't posted your models, its a bit difficult to give you a django queryset answer, but you can solve your overlapping problem by adding your users to a *set* which doesn't allow duplicates. For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

users_by_status = defaultdict(set)

for i in Status.objects.all():
    for group in i.group_set.all():
        users_by_status[i].add(group.user.pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your posted model code, the query for a given status is:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(groupsIn__receivedStatuses=some_status).distinct()
```

I'm not 100% sure that the `distinct()` call is necessary, but I seem to recall that you'd risk duplicates if a given `UserProfile` were in multiple groups that share the same status. The main point is that filtering on many-to-many relationships works using the usual underscore notation, if you use the names as defined either by `related_name` or the default related name.

Comment: @GeorgeMuresan - that query should definitely work, I just re-tested on one of my apps using the built in User/Group/Permission many-to-many chains. If it's returning an empty result, that probably indicates that `some_status` isn't set correctly.